# Provision AlbController by using AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm using AWS CDK to launch resources, I have a VPC and a basic EKS provisioned fine.

Then, I want to expose my services by using NLB ( as this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/)

I got an issue with AWS Load Balancer Controller when deployed(https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/), it says "another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress ..."

[image]

[newly added] my code to provision like this

```
const albController = new eks.AlbController(this, 'mobaAlbController', {
  cluster: this.cluster,
  version: eks.AlbControllerVersion.V2_4_1
});
```

Version:

- CDK: 2.41.0 (build 6ad48a3)
- eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_21
- eks.AlbControllerVersion.V2_4_1

Any workaround please?

Comment: I figured the issue, that's my fault, I used "taints" in the nodegroup, so the ALBController couldn't be provisioned